# How to combine mean data with different length?

Tags: list-manipulation

and would wish to reduce them such that they have the same data.

```
In[1329]:= Dimensions[NewMeanA]

Out[1329]= {6200, 2}

In[1330]:= Dimensions[NewMeanB]

Out[1330]= {12400, 2}
```

How can reduce NewMeanB to the size of 6200 or change NewMeanA to 12400 and not affecting the calculated mean values? Appreciate some help here. Thank you.

Comment: `ArrayResample` might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try.

Comment: If you want to combine the meanvalues `m1=Mean [data1,n1 ]` and `m2=Mean [data2,n2 ]` the combined meanvalue is `m=(n1 m1+n2 m2)/(n1+n2)`

Answer (score 1):

You could just double every element in `NewMeanA` to extend it so that it has the same dimensions as `NewMeanB`:

```
NewMeanA2 = Join @@ Transpose @ {NewMeanA, NewMeanA};
Dimensions[NewMeanA2]
Mean[NewMeanA] == Mean[NewMeanA2]
(* {12400, 2} *)
(* True *)
```